# Forward Debian system mail to a real e-mail address

Tags: sendmail

I have Debian running on an old Mac mini as a home router etc. with various of my crap running on it.

It produces e-mail, for example from the result of `cron` jobs. I've used `/etc/aliases` to direct this to the main user account, but I'd prefer it to go to my real e-mail address instead.

Don't want:

- send an e-mail from the command line,
- receive e-mail.

Do want:

- mail that would have gone to `root` goes *instead* to `me@example.com`.

I expect to put the crecentials for my SMPT server somewhere?

(My home router is not part of a domain -- obviously. Being in a domain seems to be a pre-requisite in everything I've read.)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Details at [http://igor.gold.ac.uk/~mas01rwb/pages/imac-ubuntu.html](http://igor.gold.ac.uk/%7Emas01rwb/pages/imac-ubuntu.html)

Short answer: `satellite`.